# Angular - Storing an array into a form array

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, tuples

this is my first question here. As I'm French, I hope you'll understand it :D
And it's not quite easy to explain.
I started learning Angular two weeks ago. Just to let you know...

It's about a collection of audio albums (EPs, CDs). 
Here's the JS interface:

```
export interface Album {
    id: number;
    artist: string;
    title: string;
    year: number;
    cover: string;
    tracks: [string, string][]; //[title, duration]
}
```

I try to build a reactive form to add new albums to an existing array that shouldn't be modified. So the tracks property cannot be an array of objects. **It must remain an array of string tuples**. For example:

```
{
    id: 5,
    artist: ' Dntel',
    title: 'Life Is Full Of Possibilities',
    year: 2001,
    cover: 'R-16855-1196613859.jpg',
    tracks: [
      ['Umbrella', '4:43'],
      ['Anywhere Anyone', '4:37'],
      ...
    ]
}
```

The form in the component:

```
export class AddAlbumComponent implements OnInit {
  albumForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    artist: ['', Validators.required],
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    year: ['', Validators.required],
    cover: [''],
    tracks: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group(
        [
          this.fb.control(''), // title input
          this.fb.control('')  // duration input
        ]
      )
    ])
  });
}
```

The actual form looks like that (sorry, the interface is in French):
[reactive form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxua7.jpg)

And now my question: how can I store the title and duration of each track in my formarray?

I tried:

```
<input type="text" id="title" [formControlName]="tracks.at(i,0)">
<input type="text" id="duration" [formControlName]="tracks.at(i,1)">
```

But the array only contains empty strings: [['0','',''],['1','','']].

Thank you!

Comment: Which array has that empty string?

Comment: The array of tracks that is contained in the array of albums.

Answer (score 1):

You has an array of array, so you need use a FromArray of FormArray

```
albumForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    artist: ['', Validators.required],
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    year: ['', Validators.required],
    cover: [''],
    tracks: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.array(  //<--this is fb.array
        [
          this.fb.control(''), // title input
          this.fb.control('')  // duration input
        ]
      )
    ])
  });
```

To avoid problems in production, you declare two auxiliars functions

```
  get tracks()
  {
    return this.albumForm.get('tracks') as FormArray
  }
  getTrack(i)
  {
    return (this.albumForm.get('tracks') as FormArray).at(i) as FormArray
  }
```

And you .html

```
<form [formGroup]="albumForm">
    <div *ngFor="let tracks of tracks.controls;let i=index" >
        <input [formControl]="getTrack(i).at(0)">
        <input [formControl]="getTrack(i).at(1)">
    </div>
</form>
```

See that we use formControl directly -not formControlName- to the inner array

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sme5wg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much Eliseo!!! Your version works like a charm! Your stackblitz link was so helpful! I've been stuck for 4 days.